# Why do some Lightroom keywords have an asterisk?

Tags: keywords, lightroom-5

Why do some keyword tags on photos have an asterisk after them?

for example:

> Jane*

These also show in lists of multiple tags:

> Bob, Jane*, mom, grill

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you select multiple photos, the asterisk * indicates that particular keyword has only been applied to a subset of the selection.

So, all the photos you've selected have the keywords Bob, mom and grill; only some (or at least one) has the keyword Jane.

Comment: does going up into the text area and manualy deleting the * have any effects? i think i did this a few times

Comment: @kacalapy Yes it applies that keyword to all photos currently selected, regardles of them having that keyword or not.